# Resize image in the client side before upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there any client side script can resize automatically the image uploaded in the input file by the user, and replace automatically the old image by the new image resized in the same input ..I want to do this to send this image to my php model after.. thanks in advance for your help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Untitled</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action="model.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="image"/>
       <input type="submit" name="do" value="submit"/>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>

<?php
$target_dir = "folder/";
$filename    = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$basename    = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir .$basename;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$tmp         = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$target_file))
{
    echo'done!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you resize it in your server? what if the user didn't resize the image and sent a big one? also, you are not checking the file type... which is dangerous, really dangerous. Anyone can upload a PHP file and execute it on your server.

Comment: To be more practical, It should occurs at server side, otherwise, it may be done using [tag:Java-Applet]. As I know, there is no way to interact with client's OS filesystem from JavaScript.

Comment: Mehdi Bounya - this is a basic code not the full code..brother read my question carefully .. ه i want that when the user upload the image the script in the client side automaticly resize the image and replace the old image by the new image resized automaticly

Comment: Brother I already read your question, **what if** the user decided to not resize the image and send it's full size?

Comment: that what i said.. the user can upload for exmple an image has 20 mega pixels in the input..so i need a script clien side can resize automaticly this image...the script who resize the image not the user did you understand me brother

Comment: Client side scripts can always be disabled, so the best way to do so is resizing it in your server side.

Comment: brother i need it for me for a personal work in my localhost not for a website

Answer (score 9):

This is how i would have solved it...

```js
// Used for creating a new FileList in a round-about way
function FileListItem(a) {
  a = [].slice.call(Array.isArray(a) ? a : arguments)
  for (var c, b = c = a.length, d = !0; b-- && d;) d = a[b] instanceof File
  if (!d) throw new TypeError("expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects")
  for (b = (new ClipboardEvent("")).clipboardData || new DataTransfer; c--;) b.items.add(a[c])
  return b.files
}

fileInput.onchange = async function change() {
  const maxWidth = 320
  const maxHeight = 240
  const result = []
  
  for (const file of this.files) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const img = await file.image()
    
    // native alternetive way (don't take care of exif rotation)
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap
    // const img = await createImageBitmap(file)
    
    // calculate new size
    const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / img.width, maxHeight / img.height)
    const width = img.width * ratio + .5 | 0
    const height = img.height * ratio + .5 | 0

    // resize the canvas to the new dimensions
    canvas.width = width
    canvas.height = height

    // scale & draw the image onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
    
    // just to preview
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)

    // Get the binary (aka blob)
    const blob = await new Promise(rs => canvas.toBlob(rs, 1))
    const resizedFile = new File([blob], file.name, file)
    result.push(resizedFile)
  }
  
  const fileList = new FileListItem(result)
  
  // temporary remove event listener since
  // assigning a new filelist to the input
  // will trigger a new change event...
  fileInput.onchange = null
  fileInput.files = fileList
  fileInput.onchange = change
}
```

```html
<!-- screw-filereader will take care of exif rotation for u -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/screw-filereader@1.4.3/index.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="image" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" name="do" value="submit" />
</form>
```

PS. it won't resize in stackoverflow due to iframe being more sandboxed and secure, work in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2oungs3/3/

Comment: thank you for your greate answer,how can i do this for  multiple values??

Comment: updated my example to work with and without `multiple` attribute

Answer (score 2):

You could draw the image to a resized canvas via the FileReader API and then use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` to get the base64 image to send to the server.

Here is a simplified example of resizing an image to 320x240:

```js
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('change', function(e) {


 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
 var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d')
 canvas.setAttribute("style", 'opacity:0;position:absolute;z-index:-1;top: -100000000;left:-1000000000;width:320px;height:240px;')
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = function() {
      canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 320, 240);
     var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      console.log(base64Image)
      // Post to server
      // sendImage(base64Image)
      
      document.body.removeChild(canvas)
     URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
  }
 img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
})

function sendImage() {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var ajax = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajax.open('POST', 'https://example/route', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {
                // Success
            } else {
                // Fail
            }
        }
    };

    ajax.send(data);
}
```

```html
<input id="example" type="file" />
```

And then on the server:

```
// or however you want to get the posted contents.
$png = isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]) ? $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] : file_get_contents("php://input");
if (strpos($png, 'data:image/png;base64,') === 0) {
$png = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $png);
$png = str_replace(' ', '+', $png);
$png = base64_decode($png);
}

file_put_contents($image_path, $png);
```

**EDIT**
The code now includes a way to upload the image to the server.
You could also use *jQuery* or the more modern fetch API to upload the image.
[JsFiddle available here](https://jsfiddle.net/vrrk2u95/14/)

Comment: It works but you will CROP the image instead of resizing it.

Comment: yes this will crop instead of resize